# Keydown subroutine on VB 2017 will not activate?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, subroutine

I want my object to move down when I press keydown, but it will not move it just stays in the static it stays in the same place. The subroutine won't activate and I don't know why. This is for a school project and I've tried asking my peers and my teacher but this is my last resort so please help me.

```
Public Class [form]
    Private Sub [form]_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        MsgBox("yes")
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
            [picturebox].Left += 5

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am using Visual Basic 2017 because that's what my school is telling us to use for this project. Why isn't my subroutine working?

Comment: Do you have something on that Form that can take the keyboard input? As a TextBox, a Button etc. Have you tried setting .`KeyPreview = true`? -- Unrelated: If those in brackets are the actual names of your Controls, give them more meaningful names and remove the brackets. You should also remove the MessageBox. Use `Control.WriteLine()` or `Debug.WriteLine()` to print some text on the  Output or Immediate window.

Comment: I highly recommend that you don't name your VB project objects using reserved words (i.e. [form] and [picturebox]).